# Map not centralizing to the position of marker on first load in PHP

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a dialog box which has input field for selecting the map.I have put default latitude and longitude values and the marker is also available in the map.I have provided the default location to Abudhabi.But when the map loads for the first time,its showing the region of India.
I have used the following code.

```
 <script>
    var directionsDisplay,
    directionsService,
    map,chicago;

    if(!window.google||!window.google.maps){  
      var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=MYKEY&region=AE&' +
            'callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
    else{ 
      initialize();
    }


    function initialize() { //
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); 
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(24.2991738,54.69727739999996);
          if(($("#latitude_val").val().length >3) || ($("#longitude_val").val().length>3))
          {
           chicago =  new google.maps.LatLng($("#latitude_val").val(), $("#longitude_val").val());  
      }
      else
      { 
          codeAddress(function(num) {
      //console.log('{{{{}}}}'+num);

          }); 
      }  
      var mapOptions = { zoom:4, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, center: chicago }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);  
      var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:chicago,
      map:map,
      draggable:true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
      });

      marker.setMap(map);

      google.maps.event.addListener(
                marker,
                'drag',
                function() {
                    document.getElementById('latitude_val').value = marker.position.lat();
                    document.getElementById('longitude_val').value = marker.position.lng();
                }

            ); 
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
          placeMarker(event.latLng,marker);
        });
      //directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }

    function fail(){
         alert('navigator.geolocation failed, may not be supported'); 
      }

      function placeMarker(location,marker) {
          if ( marker ) {
            marker.setPosition(location);
          } else {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: location,
              map: map
            });
          }
          document.getElementById('latitude_val').value = marker.position.lat();
          document.getElementById('longitude_val').value = marker.position.lng();
    } 

    function codeAddress(callback) {   

      var address = document.getElementById('schoolcity').value;
      if(address.length>3)
      {
          geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            chicago = [results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng()];
            callback(chicago);
          } else {
              console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);  
              chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
            }
          }); 
      }
      else
      {
          chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
      } 
    }
 </script>
```

When we open the dialog after that,then the map is centralized to the marker position.
I need to centralize the map where the pointer is placed on the first loading of the dialog.

[image: First image when I load the page .It has markers,but I need to scroll]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (including the required HTML).   If I run your code with what I expect your HTML to be, it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I modifiy the url from `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=MYKEY&region=AE&callback=initialize` to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&region=AE&callback=initialize`,it worked for me. I have removed the version parameter from the url